# Why not in decimals?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a Seekbar that controls the timer at the bottom.I'm curious that when i move the seek bar why doesn't the value goes in decimal?

**Here is the code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SeekBar timeController = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.timeController);
        final TextView tV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tV);

        timeController.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

                int minutes =  progress / 60;
                int seconds =  progress - minutes*60;

                tV.setText(String.valueOf(minutes) + ":" +String.valueOf(seconds) );
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: They are defined as ints. What would be holding any decimal values? Also, you can set seconds to `progress % 60`. Not sure if it's faster, but it's easier to see what it's doing.

Comment: I have tried by changing it to double but it goes from 0.0 to 1.0 and then 2.0

Comment: It looks like progress is an int, so I'm not sure there's a way to be more precise than the nearest second: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html

Answer (score 0):

You have your minutes and seconds variables declared as `int`. Change them to `double` to show decimals.

Comment: I have tried by changing it to double but it goes from 0.0 to 1.0 and then 2.0

Comment: Try making progress a double as well